# How to send (POST) a .json file selected via an input file control on client side HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

Hi I currently have a form to select a file for upload to an endpoint that requires the payload to be encoded as JSON.

Currently, I have the following form but it is multipart/form-data. I do not think it is possible to encode a form submission as application/json without resorting to something like ajax....

```html
<form action = "/upload" method = "POST" 
         enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         <input type = "file" name = "file" />
         <input type = "submit"/>
</form>
```

Is it possible using ajax to read the file selected in the form and send the contents as a json payload to the POST url endpoint? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible by using the [`FileReader API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to parse the file to a string and send the string to the server as encoded JSON.

```html
<form id="upload-form" action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" />
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

---

First of we'll need a function that takes in a `File` and parses it to a string with the `FileReader`. The `readFileAsText` function returns a Promise which will resolve once the file has been parsed as text.

The result should be the content of the file as a string. That string is the JSON that we'll send to the server.

```js
const readFileAsText = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = ({ target }) => {
    resolve(target.result);
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
});
```

**Edit:** nowadays you can perform this same process of reading the file as string with the [`Blob.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/text) method. A `File` instance has this method as well and is used like this:

```
/**
 * In this context the file variable is an instance of File.
 */

// In an async context
const text = await file.text();

// Outside an async context.
file.text().then(text => {
  // handle the text.
});
```

---

Next will be the AJAX part of sending your payload to the server. We do this by using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). Here we specify the content type in the headers and create a POST request with a payload that contains JSON.

After the request is made it checks the response from the server and expects a JSON response from the server. Be sure to return a JSON response from the server side.

```js
const sendJSON = async json => {
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  };

  const response = await fetch('/upload', {
    headers,
    method: 'POST',
    body: json
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Sending file caused an error - ${response.statusText}`);
  }

  return response.json();
};
```

Now we'll try to piece it together. In the following snippet we listen for the `submit` event on the form. When the form submits, stop the default behavior and overwrite what we need to do on submit.

1. Get the values from the form with the [`FormData API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData). This enables us to extract the values from the form without having to select a specific element.
2. Select the `file` from the `formData` object and pass it to the `readFileAsText` function (or use the `text()` method on the file). The result should be the JSON in the file.
3. Now pass the `json` from the file into the `sendJSON` function and off it goes.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#upload-form');

form.addEventListener('submit', async event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const formData = new FormData(event.target);
  const file = formData.get('file');

  // No file size means no file.
  if (file.size === 0) {
    return; // Do nothing.
  }

  try {
    const json = await readFileAsText(file);
    const response = await sendJSON(json);
    console.log(response);
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Many thanks, that solved the issue. Will accept answer and upvote! Thanks again, appreciated :)

Comment: Wait, I noticed that the title question is different from what you're asking. My understanding was that you wanted to send the file as JSON, but you're meaning to read the JSON from the file and send the content, right?

Comment: yes, correct...trying to read the JSON from file and send the JSON content as application/json to rest API endpoint

Comment: Alright, my bad. I've modified the answer so that it will now just send the **content** of the `.json` file, which is already JSON to start with. So that saves a step of parsing the result from the `FileReader` to JSON. Let me know if this still works.

Comment: Update gives an error...Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'....fails at  reader.readAsText(file); in readFileAsText function.

Comment: That should be unrelated. Did you forget to pass a `.json` file to the input?

Comment: Not sure....I think it is likely something like that...will try and step away from coding awhile and then come back to it later...my brain is frazzled...Many thanks for amending the solution...